# How to increase LilyPond horizontal spacing?

Tags: lilypond, engraving

I'm trying to create some very simple music note worksheets with LilyPond. I'm afraid I'm still not familiar with the language itself, but here is what I'm looking for:

```
\version "2.20.0"

\relative c' {
  c d e f g a b c
}
```

This generates:

[image: C major scale with default Lilypond spacing]

I'd like to double the horizontal spacing between each of the notes. Google tells me this has something to do with layout but I'm at a loss at how to actually do it.

Answer (score 10):

This is accomplished with the `SpacingSpanner spacing-increment` property ([see the Lilypond documentation](https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.21/Documentation/internals/spacing_002dspanner_002dinterface))

For example, this code

```
% LilyBin
\score{
    \relative c' {
        c d e f g a b c
    }
}
```

produces

[image: Notes with default spacing]

but this code

```
% LilyBin
\score{
    \relative c' {
        c d e f g a b c
    }

    \layout{
        \context {
            \Score
            \override SpacingSpanner spacing-increment = 4
        }
    }
}
```

produces

[image: Notes with spacing-increment = 4]

Answer (score 4):

In addition to Aaron's answer, another option is to use the `base-shortest-duration` property as discussed in the documentation [here](http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.18/Documentation/notation/changing-horizontal-spacing).

This property basically uses a note duration as its unit of measurement, so `#(ly:make-moment 1/16)` will use a sixteenth note, `#(ly:make-moment 1/8)` will use an eighth, etc. (Although you can use any fraction, not just fractions that suggest clear note values.) This means that the smaller the number (like `1/16` as opposed to `1/8`), the more spaced out the score will be.

```
\version "2.20.0"

\score{
    \relative c' {
        c d e f g a b c
    }

    \layout{
        \context {
            \Score
            \override SpacingSpanner.base-shortest-duration = #(ly:make-moment 1/16)
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

And for anyone that doesn't know LilyPond but it interested in learning it, I highly recommend the [YouTube tutorial series](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLHi8BvxILUV6x9FqEmZiYrEj6VMGmTKjt) by soundsfromsound.

Answer (score 4):

While the answers already provided do answer your question directly,  I suspect that what you are trying to achieved can be accomplished with simpler commands.

---

The `\break` command can be used to begin a new line. This will consequently stretch out the preceding music to fill the line – justified according to the note values.

However, the break command doesn't work for the last line (because there is nothing to break to).
In this case `ragged-last` (which goes into to layout block) can be turned off.  This has a similar effect – stretching out the last line to fill the page nicely.

```
\score {
    \relative c' {
        c d e f |
        \break  
        g a b c |
    }

    \layout {
        ragged-last = ##f
    }
}
```

[image: score using break and ragged-last]